# Is uniform convergence needed?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose one has a series of the type $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)$$ and know that it converges to $0$ uniformly for all x in a closed interval $[a,b]$. Is this enough to determine that $a_n$ and $b_n$ need to be $0$ for all $n$? I strongly suspect so, but wonder if there is an extra step needed. What if convergence were only point wise? What would fail?

Comment: What is $a$ and $b$? If the context is about Fourier series, then you should have $b-a=2\pi$ in the example you give.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider for example $$f(x) = \cases{0 & if $0 \le x \le \pi$\cr x-\pi & if $\pi < x < 2\pi$\cr}$$
Then the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,b]$ if $0 < a < b < \pi$, but is not identically $0$.

Comment: Thanks. What if this phenomenon was excluded by assumption e.g. $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the actual Fourier coefficients of the function $0$ defined, say on $[0,2\pi]$ and prolonged by continuity. $0$ is continuous so there is uniform convergence of the Fourier series, but what is it that allows me to conclude that the Fourier coefficients are $0$ following this line of reasoning?

Comment: You want to show that the actual Fourier coefficients of the function $0$ are all $0$?  That's not hard...

Comment: No, of course that's a straightforward computation, I'm rather trying to understand why it shouldn't work if there is only pointwise convergence

Comment: @Karl: but that was your *first* question, isn't it? "Is this enough to determine that ..." Yes when the convergence is uniform.

Comment: But it doesn't work even if you have uniform convergence!  I don't understand how you're proposing to exclude my counterexample.  The Fourier series of a smooth function on the circle ($[0,2\pi]$ with $0$ and $2\pi$ identified) converges uniformly to that function.  If the function happens to be $0$ on $[a,b]$ but not on all of $[0,2\pi]$, then you have uniform convergence to $0$ on the interval $[a,b]$, but the coefficients are not all $0$.